# Checking checkbox for ID depending on value/validation from other sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the sample sheet containing the apps script:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AOzYMVqOqww4bUfSigDWz6gL6tmESfQxuKw4auNS4kU/edit?usp=sharing

I have a master list that tracks if a transaction letter is sent. 3 letters are supposed to be sent after the transaction date - 1st, 3rd, and 6th months after the initial transaction date so there are 3 checkboxes for each ID. If a letter is sent, right now I manually check one checkbox off depending on what letter month it was for. I created a second sheet that will show all the earliest dates for each ID that is not checked and that is before the date on cell B2. My goal is when I run the script, it will check off all the corresponding checkboxes where the Customer ID and Date is matching.

Here is my current apps script code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh1 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1AOzYMVqOqww4bUfSigDWz6gL6tmESfQxuKw4auNS4kU','Payment Due by Date!A4:D');
  var sh2 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('1AOzYMVqOqww4bUfSigDWz6gL6tmESfQxuKw4auNS4kU','Master List!A2:K');

  for(var i = 0; i < sh1.values.length; i++){
    var sh1Id = sh1.values[i][0];     //sheet1 ID
    var sh1DD = sh1.values[i][2];     //sheet1 date
    
    for(var j = 0; j < sh2.values.length; j++){
      var sh2Id = sh2.values[j][0];    //sheet2 ID
      var sh2m1d = sh2.values[j][3];   //sheet2 month1 date
      var sh2m1c = sh2.values[j][4];   //sheet2 month1 checkbox
      var sh2m3d = sh2.values[j][5];   //sheet2 month3 date
      var sh2m3c = sh2.values[j][6];   //sheet2 month3 checkbox
      var sh2m6d = sh2.values[j][7];   //sheet2 month6 date
      var sh2m6c = sh2.values[j][8];   //sheet2 month6 checkbox
      
      //Logger.log(sh2m1c);
      
      //compare the ID & month and check the corresponding checkbox
      if(sh1Id == sh2Id && sh1DD  == sh2m1d)
        sh2m1c = "TRUE";
      else if(sh1Id == sh2Id && sh1DD  == sh2m3d)
        sh2m3c = "TRUE";
      else if(sh1Id == sh2Id && sh1DD  == sh2m6d)
        sh2m6c = "TRUE";
  }
  }
}
```

When I checked the logger, the loop is I think getting the values(correct me if I'm wrong). I dont know if my loop is incorrectly ran or if how im checking the checkbox is wrong.

EDIT: A specific example in my sheet of what im trying to do:

If in the Payment Due date this row is present

| Customer ID | Customer Name | Payment Due Date | Payment Mo Due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1042 | Tom, C | 6/5/2020 | 6th Mo Due |

When the script runs I want the checkbox under the 6th Mo Due in Master List for ID 1042 to be checked.

| Customer ID | Customer Name | Transaction Date | 1st Mo Due | 1st Mo Sent? | 3rd Mo Due | 3rd Mo Sent? | 6th Mo Due | 6th Mo Sent? | Last Unchecked Date (CALCULATED) | Last Date Due (CALCULATED) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1042 | Tom, C | 12/5/2019 | 1/5/2020 | TRUE | 3/5/2020 | TRUE | 6/5/2020 | FALSE | 6/5/2020 | 6th Mo Due |

So under the 6th Mo Sent? column, the checkbox will be checked which is now FALSE or unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  function myFunction() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master List');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Payment Due By Date');
  var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  //Use getDisplayValues so the complier won't automatically convert the date based on timezone.
  var sheet1_val = sheet1.getRange(2, 1, 12, 11).getDisplayValues();
  //get Ids and merge into 1 dimensional array
  var sheet1_ids = [].concat(...sheet1.getRange(2, 1, 12, 1).getDisplayValues());
  var sheet2_val = sheet2.getRange(4,1,sheet2.getLastRow()-3, 4).getDisplayValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < sheet2_val.length; i++){
    var customer_id = sheet2_val[i][0];
    var pay_due_date = sheet2_val[i][2];
    //check if customer id exists in the id list (sheet1_ids)
    if (sheet1_ids.indexOf(customer_id) !== -1) {
      //get the position/index of the id
      var index = sheet1_ids.indexOf(customer_id);
      //I used 3 and 8 since we only need the column D-H
      for(var j = 3; j < 8; j++){
        //Iterate and check each column if match to the pay_due_date
        if(pay_due_date == sheet1_val[index][j]){
          //assign new value
          sheet1_val[index][j+1] = "TRUE";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  var lastRow = sheet1.getLastRow();
  //merge subarrays with same index
  var sheet1Transpose = transpose(sheet1_val);
  var request = {
    'valueInputOption': 'USER_ENTERED',
    'data': [
      {
        'range': 'Master List!E2:E'+lastRow,
        'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS',
        'values': [sheet1Transpose[4]]
      },
      {
        'range': 'Master List!G2:G'+lastRow,
        'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS',
        'values': [sheet1Transpose[6]]
      },
      {
        'range': 'Master List!I2:I'+lastRow,
        'majorDimension': 'COLUMNS',
        'values': [sheet1Transpose[8]]
      }
    ]
  };

  var response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(request, spreadsheetId);
}

function transpose(matrix) {
  return matrix[0].map((col, i) => matrix.map(row => row[i]));
}
```

**Note:** *Make sure to add Google Sheets in Services.*

### Example:

**Payment Due Date:**

[image: PDD]

**Before:**

[image: ex1]

**After:**
[image]

### Reference:

- [getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [Writing to multiple ranges](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing#write_to_multiple_ranges)

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, the checking of the checkbox for the matching id/date is working but it is removing all the formula in the master list. Do you know why this is happening? This is important that it doesnt happen for my case because some of my columns are all formulas like dragging down vlookups so my formulas are not only present in row 2 but also in the last row.

Comment: Just an added note. Formulas in the Payment Due by Date sheet is not removed.

Comment: Do checkbox populated using formula?

Comment: Yes they do. It is working as intended, it's just removing all the formulas in the master list. Is it because we are replacing the whole row with the values instead of just the cells with the checkbox?

Comment: For example, the dates under 1st Mo Due, 3rd Mo Due, 6th Mo Due, and Last Unchecked all had calculations. When I ran the script, it removed the calculations. The list on the Payment Due by Date sheet is populated from the Last Unchecked Date in Master List, so I was hoping once they were checked in the Master List, they would be removed from the Payment Due by Date sheet.

Comment: @googlesheettest - yes, the code replaced the rows from column D-I. I updated my answer so that it will only update the columns with checkbox.